# Submitting form to Struts Action using AJAX

Tags: java, ajax

```
function callProcessFastaFiles(){
    var form=document.forms[0];
    document.forms[0].action="/BioInformaticsOnlineTool/fromProcessFasta.do";
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

I am calling this function to send a form to the server. How can I change this using ajax so that after server is done, the response comes on the same page?

Comment: good [reference](http://www.raistudies.com/struts-1/ajax-with-struts-example/) for your requirement

Comment: i have to send files using ajax.i cannot get the values and send it in the post using name ,value pairs...for file uploading how can i proceed.

Comment: Was your question mean that ? How could  we know the exact requirement of your with out mentioning here

Comment: Sorry for that .Can you give me any idea how to do that .Its an urgent requirement.Thanx